# What does "Voltage Holding Characteristic Minimum" refer to for a supercap?

Tags: supercapacitor

In supercap datasheets (e.g. [this](https://content.kemet.com/datasheets/KEM_S6015_FY.pdf), extract below) there is a column in the ratings table called "Voltage Holding Characteristic Minimum". What does this refer to?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's the voltage it drops to (due to leakage) if you charge it up to the nominal voltage, and then disconnect it and just let it sit.

In another datasheet, Minimum Holding Voltage was accompanied by the footnote:

*Minimum voltage at 24 hours after charging for 1 hour at 5VDC.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the bottom of the data sheet, the Voltage Holding Characteristic refers to the self-discharge behavior of the capacitor.  It is measured by charging the capacitor to 5 volts and then measuring the voltage after 24 hours has elapsed. For these particular capacitors, the voltage after 24 hours will be at least 4.2 volts.